# Alternative of ABS() in Mysql for JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

**I have a Table like:-**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Score |
+----+-------+
| 3  | -10   |
| 2  | -11   |
| 4  | -9    |
| 5  | 1     |
| 1  | 12    |
+----+-------+
```

**and I am Expecting output**

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 12    |
| 2  | -11   |
| 3  | -10   |
| 4  | -9    |
| 5  | 1     |
+----+-------+
```

**Although I have a query**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
ORDER BY 
       ABS(score) DESC;
```

I want a replacement of this for JPQL/JPA.

Comment: Doesn't JPQL support ABS()?  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvq

Answer (score 1):

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE ABS(p.price)<50.0");
```

Got from the [source](http://www.roseindia.net/jpa/eclipsejpaexamples/abs.shtml)